# How to assure that the calculation for mean and variance read from a file is correct?

Tags: c#, file-io, mean, variance

I am working on a project about loading data from a file, and computing basic statistics (mean, variance).

The file has 20k lines and each line has 23 columns.
The file is as follows:

```
 person_id   range1   value1    range2   value2  ...  range11   value11
```

A person_id may or may not have a value in a range, and the same person_id may appear at different lines of the file because it may have different values in the same range.

I need to calculate the mean and variance for each person at each range. The result should be

```
  person_id   range1_mean   range1_variance   range2_mean   range2_variance  ...
```

My question:

After doing the calculation, how to make sure that I do not miss any data and also get the correct results for mean and variance?

I find that some persons (more than 20) have different mean values but the same variance.

Comment: You could create test cases, and make sure your calculation matches a calculation by hand on them.

Comment: @Dan Getz, it is impossible to do it manually because there may be hundreds of values for one person_id. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that the formulas you've coded in C# are correct, in checking your results for one given file, I suggest that you use another tool. Use one which is known as reliable, in order to **cross check** the computed statistics.

For example, you could use Excel as your **reference** tool.

Comment: if I use Excel, how to assure that the Excel file really get the correct results ? If Excel tool and C# tool have different results, how to now which one is correct? if they are same, how to know both are correct ? Thanks !!!

Comment: What do you want to verify exactly? I thought you want to check that your C# formulas for mean and variance are correct. If this is true, you can trust Excel for the mean and variance formulas, use it as your **reference** tool.